# How can I adjust the Wordpress Twentyeleven theme so that the page width is 100% and centered?

Tags: css, wordpress, width

I am trying to adjust my Wordpress theme, and I've created a child theme based on twentyeleven. The main issue I have right now is with the width.

Please take a look at a live sample I created using just HTML and CSS. This is what I am trying to make my wordpress theme look like:
http://danapaigetrentlage.com/cfsa-comps/lff-profilepage.html

I want the page width to be 100% so that the sky background and white-wrap bleed horizontally off the page, but I also want the content to be centered within the page.

You can see how far I've gotten towards this goal by looking at my wordpress site:
http://danapaigetrentlage.com/cfsa-test/

You can see the page is wider than 1000px (the theme's default width), but still not full-width, and there's a horizontal scrollbar, instead of the content just being centered.

I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Dana

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's just a case of setting body's padding to 0.

```
body {
    padding: 0;
}
```